# How to delete nodes and subnodes using XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have xml as under

```
<databaseserver>
   <server name="server1" serverid="1">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="1" dbname="db1" />
        <database dbid="2" dbname="db2" />
    </databases>
   </server>
   <server name="server2" serverid="2">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="1" dbname="db1" />
        <database dbid="2" dbname="db2" />
    </databases>
   </server>
   <server name="server3" serverid="3">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="1" dbname="db1" />
        <database dbid="2" dbname="db2" />
    </databases>
   </server>
</databaseserver>
```

I want to delete the nodes and it's subnodes whose serverid="1".

Final output will be

```
<databaseserver>   
   <server name="server2" serverid="2">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="1" dbname="db1" />
        <database dbid="2" dbname="db2" />
    </databases>
   </server>
   <server name="server3" serverid="3">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="1" dbname="db1" />
        <database dbid="2" dbname="db2" />
    </databases>
   </server>
</databaseserver>
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

xDoc.Descendants("server")
    .First(s => s.Attribute("serverid").Value == "1")
    .Remove();

var newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

XPath is also possible

```
xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//server[@serverid='1']").Remove();
```