# Append a new node to existing XML using XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have xml as under

```
<databaseserver>
   <server name="server1" serverid="1">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="1" dbname="db1" />
        <database dbid="2" dbname="db2" />
    </databases>
   </server>
   <server name="server2" serverid="2">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="1" dbname="db1" />
        <database dbid="2" dbname="db2" />
    </databases>
   </server>   
</databaseserver>
```

How  can I append a new node

```
<server name="" serverid="3">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="" dbname="" />        
    </databases>
   </server>
```

to the existing xml such that the final output looks as

```
<databaseserver>
   <server name="server1" serverid="1">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="1" dbname="db1" />
        <database dbid="2" dbname="db2" />
    </databases>
   </server>
   <server name="server2" serverid="2">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="1" dbname="db1" />
        <database dbid="2" dbname="db2" />
    </databases>
   </server> 
   <server name="" serverid="3">
    <databases>
            <database dbid="" dbname="" />        
    </databases>
   </server>  
</databaseserver>
```

Comment: previous question was `How to delete nodes` now how to append, what is the next?

Comment: How about reading some docs about Linq2Xml, instead of asking every part of your problem seperately.

Comment: Thank you for your question. It's all part of the learning process. What's next? Ask as many questions as you need to; it helps the audience, as well as yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xDoc` is the same as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17010032/1906557)

```
xDoc.Root.Add(new XElement("server", 
                new XAttribute("name","server4"),
                new XAttribute("serverid","4"),
                new XElement("databases", 
                    new XElement("database", 
                        new XAttribute("dbid","db4"), 
                        new XAttribute("dbname","name4")))));
```